# How to integrate simple js file in react native mobile app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am not a react native developer, however my question is based on react native app.
Me and my team is in a discussion to integrate an external js file into react native mobile application.
The js file runs flawlessly in normal HTML. So question is can we use the same js in react native, if so how? Please advise with a sample code if possible.

Thanks in advance.

[Update]
Sample code in the js file.

```
function addition(number1, number2){
    var result = number1 + number2;
    return result.
}
```

Now I want to use the complete js file as it is in react native mobile app.
Inside component, i should be able to use -

> 'addition(10, 20)'

Comment: I you would like to get a reasonable answer, you should specify the details: what the script is doing etc. Assuming the script does some DOM manipulations this question makes no sense

Comment: @Rostyslav i have updated my question, will this help? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you need to study and learn `React` and `React-Native`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View,TouchableOpacity,Text} from 'react-native';

export default ()=> {
  let [sum,setSum]=React.useState(null);
  let addition=(num1,num2)=>setSum(num1+num2);

  return (
   <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
     <Text>{sum}</Text>
     <TouchableOpacity
        style={{padding:20, backgroundColor:'tomato'}}
        onPress={()=>addition(10,20)}
     >
        <Text>Run</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
  )
}
```